# What type should my class be to access a class and the class it extended?

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

you have

```
public class Question
```

and

```
public class MultipleChoice extends Question
```

and

```
public class SurveyQuestions
```

where SurveyQuestions has

```
private static List<Question> q = new ArrayList<Question>();
```

In main you keep adding questions and all the things questions are composed of to the list.

Once done, you want to iterate over the list

```
for (Question q : SurveyQuestions.getInstance().getListOfQuestions())
```

**Question**: What type should "q" be so that it has access to both Question and MultipleChoice?

Comment: @Ignacio Yep, as the reply is so easy to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "access to" you mean "access to the methods of"- you can't have it as `MultipleChoice` because some questions might not be such. So it has to be `Question`, and then you can check if it is a multiple-choice by `if(q instanceof MultipleChoice)`

Answer (score 1):

You should make it `Question`.

You can't make it `MultipleChoice` as a plain `Question` *is not* a `MultipleChoice`... but a `MultipleChoice` *is a* `Question`. So `Question` can represent both types.